# install mapbox on java android studio project

Tags: android, maps, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm developing an android application with java and I want to integrate Mapbox, I followed all the documentation here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/

I requested both tokens successfully and added the dependency in the build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    implementation ("com.mapbox.maps:android:10.1.0")
}
```

The problem is when I go to paste the following code into settings.gradle:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven (){
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = "mapbox"
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN
            }
        }
    }
}
```

url and basic are not recognized and I get several errors, in particular:

- Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
- Unresolved reference: basic

How can i fix this problem during the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should look like below, I compiled this with Android Studio Giraffe.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven")
            authentication {
                create<BasicAuthentication>("basic")
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = "mapbox"
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN
            }
        }
    }
}
```